# Firebase Sing in Page doenst Work Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to make a sign up page with Firebase, but I'm getting the following error:
"Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null"

1.I have the issue on my Phone and on the Emulator

2.Internet is working Connection via Wlan.

3.I checked the gradle and the google-service.Json and all is correct

4.Sign in Method: Email/Password is active

5.Android Studio is up to date

I've seen this question often but none of the replies work for me.
I think its a small detail that I'm missing.

Thanks for your help.
Apfelmann

```
package com.example.taskboard;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegWindow extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener    {
    TextView RegBack;
    EditText EmailReg, PasswordReg;
    Button ButtonReg;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg_window);

        TextView back = findViewById(R.id.RegBack);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button BReg = findViewById(R.id.ButtonReg);
        BReg.setOnClickListener(this);
        EmailReg = findViewById(R.id.EmailReg);
        PasswordReg = findViewById(R.id.PasswordReg);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();









                                                        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())   {
            case R.id.ButtonReg:
                reg();
                break;

            case R.id.RegBack:
                finish();
                break;

                            }

                                }
    public void reg(){
        String Email = EmailReg.getText().toString().trim();
        String Password = PasswordReg.getText().toString().trim();

        if(Email.isEmpty())         {
            EmailReg.setError("Bitte Email eingeben");
            EmailReg.requestFocus();
            return;
                                    }
        if(Password.isEmpty())      {
            PasswordReg.setError("Bitte ein Password eingeben");
            PasswordReg.requestFocus();
            return;
                                    }
        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()){
            EmailReg.setError("Keine Gültige Email eingegeben");
            EmailReg.requestFocus();
            return;
                                                            }

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(RegWindow.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            Toast.makeText(RegWindow.this, "Danke für die Regestrierung", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{


                            Toast.makeText(RegWindow.this, "Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });




                     }
                                                                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

i selected the wrong project in Firebase and the Sign-In Method was disabled. Shame on me.
But im happy it´s working now.

i used this Toast to show me the error Massage i needed.

```
Toast.makeText(RegWindow.this, "Fehler"+ task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was issue in email, i put space in the last of email which i didn't see, then i resolve this by adding email.trim() method while authenticating user.

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.trim(), password: password);
```